# lxml HtmlElement drop_tree failed

Tags: python, lxml

I use lxml to remove some ul tags, like this:

```
for ele in doc.iter('ul'):
    if len(ele.findall('.//a')) / len(ele.findall('.//li')) >= 2:
        ele.drop_tree()
```

but this does not work, not remove any ul tag.

And if I do like this :

```
 for ele in doc.iter('ul'):
     ele.drop_tree()
```

all ul tags removed.
Anyone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the value of "len(ele.findall('.//li'))" mab be zero,you can try:

```
html = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring("<root><child>Child 1</child><child>Child 2</child><another>Child 3</another><another>Child 4</another></root>")
for elem in html.iter('another'):
    for sub in elem.findall('.'):
        if 'Child 4' in sub.itertext():
            html.remove(sub)
print(lxml.html.tostring(html, encoding='unicode'))
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I plus one to len(ele.findall('.//li')), result not be changed.